# Emboss an Image in HALCON

Tags: halcon

**Original Image:**

[image: Original Image]

**OpenCV Processed Image:**

[image: OpenCV Processed Image]

The first Image is the original.

The second image is OpenCV's processed image.

I want to realize the effect in HALCON too.

Can someone give me advise on which method or HALCON operator to use?

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia ([Image embossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_embossing)) this can be achieved by a convolutional filter. In the example you provided it seems that the embossing direction is South-West.

In HALCON you can use the operator [convol_image](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/1805/en/convol_image.html) to calculate the correlation between an image and an arbitrary filter mask. The filter would be similar to this:

[Embossing filter matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878as.gif)

To apply such a filter matrix in HDevelop you can use the following line of code:

```
convol_image (OriginalImage, EmbossedImage, [3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1], 0)
```